# accessing lambda value passed to function python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, lambda, arguments

I am trying to access the value of the lambda functions when i pass the value on the same line as the function is called. the only way i can get the value is to return(f). Is there any way to access the value before this and compare it to other values?

```
def func(f):
    return(f)

func(lambda x: x*2)(3)
6
```

Comment: what is the question? access what variable? where?

Comment: What do you mean the *value* of it?

Comment: when i pass a lambda function to func() and give the lambda x the value of (3) at the end of the func() call line. it passes the (3) to the lambda in func() and yield the value 6. how do i access that six value in the body of the function.

Comment: In the body of which function? Please expound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The `(3)` is passed to what `func()` returns, so the `func` can't access it. This is what happens:

```
def func(f):
    return f  # parenthesis unnecessary.
func(lambda x: x*2)(3)
```

Which, when the lambda function is returned, turns to:

```
(lambda x: x*2)(3)
```

Which is:

```
3*2  # 6
```

This way, you see that the function does not interact with the argument passed to the lambda. You can't access it directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure about your use case - are you trying to do something like this?

```
def func(f, *args):
  result = f(*args)
  # Do some simple comparison with the result of the lambda
  myValue = 8
  msg = "8 > %d" if 8>result else "8 <= %d"
  return msg % result

print(func(lambda x:x*2, 3))  # prints 8 > 6
print(func(lambda x:x*2, 5))  # prints 8 <= 10
print(func(lambda x:x**2, 3)) # prints 8 <= 9
```

As you can see, doing that requires changing `func` to accept the parameter for the lambda along with the lambda itself.